# Models exported using Blender cannot be used directly by the GLTF Loader

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, gltf

Models exported using Blender cannot be used directly by the GLTF Loader and need to be re-exported in the Threejs Edit page.

[image: screenshot of JavaScript code]

This is the message on the console when used directly (Sample Models using glTF work fine).

[image: screenshot of console]

The problem is that the export configuration of Blender is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. Here is the export configuration of Blender.If anyone could pinpoint what the error, I'd be glad.

[image: screenshot of Blender export configuration]

Comment: The direct import phenomenon is that the program is always in the progress function without calling onload (console.log(GLTF)).

Comment: I could have put the GLB files I exported from Blender into the Threejs Editor and exported again and it would have loaded successfully, but the text size three Editor gave me was 5-6 times the size of the source file, which was too big

Comment: It's difficult to find the exact reason for it not working with the given information.

The console shows 30 errors. One of them could be the reason it's not working. If the gltf works in editor, it's not an issue with blender but rather with the code.